# Parsing tab delimited file then resulting array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I have a tab delimited file which I'm parsing, I then need to parse the resulting arrays.

This is how I'm parsing the file:

```
$fp = fopen('myFile.txt', 'r');

while ( !feof($fp) )
{
  $line = fgets($fp, 2048);

  $delimiter = "\t";
  $array = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
}
```

To check the data I try `print_r($array);` which gives me for example:

```
Array ( [0] => Customer Name [1] => Customer Email [2] => Date [3] => Test Date)
Array ( [0] => John Smith [1] => john@gmail.com [2] => Date [3] => 01/01/1985)
```

How can I parse this? I'm trying the following but it produces a blank page.

```
foreach($array as $a) {
    echo $a.'<br>';
}
```

I'm quite new to arrays but can clearly see nothing is enclosed in quotes which I guess is causing me a problem. Should the quotes be added during the parsing of the tab delimited file? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your use of `!feof`: you're checking if you haven't already reached the end of the file, and that's fine, but you're not checking the return value of `fgets`. The last line in a file often is just a new-line character, so on your last iteration, it's not unlikely that `$line` ends up being an empty string.
You're also re-assigning `$array`, each time replacing the previous values you assigned to it. If the loop you posted is situated *outside* of the `while` loop, it's not unlikely that what you're doing is actually this:

```
$line = '';//as explained, $line might be an empty string
$array = str_getcsv($line, "\t");//which is $array = array();
```

If you then attempt to lop over this empty array, you're not going to echo anything:

```
foreach (array() as $a)
    echo $a;//there are no values to echo...
```

Your best bet is to construct a 2D array:

```
$array = array();
while(...)
    $array[] = $lineAsArray;
```

This is pseudo-code, because the while-loop you have can be simplified *a lot*:
Why not use [the `fgetcsv` function](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) with a custom delimiter?

```
$fh = fopen('myFile.txt', 'r');
if (!$fh)
    exit(1);//handle error
while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 2048, "\t"))
{//line is an array of CSV values now
    echo implode('<br>', $line), '<br>';//echo all values
}
```

That's all there is too it. Instead of `implode` you can loop over line, but seeing as you're just echoing all values, followed by `<br>`, I figured using `implode` just made more sense.

I don't know for sure what your file looks like, but the longest line *might* be longer than 2048 bytes, you can take advantage of the fact that PHP can handle a `0` length argument. If the length is zero, the line will be read until an EOL, or EOF is encountered:

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t"))
```

That'll work just fine...

***Bottom line:***
I think that you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
$fh = fopne('myFile.txt', 'r');
if (!$fh)
    exit(1);//handle error
$array = array();
$alternative = array();
while($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t"))
{
    $array[] =  $line;
    //or if you simply want to echo:
    $alternative[] = implode('<br>', $line);
}
//the short alternative
echo implode('<br>', $alternative);
//the long way:
foreach ($array as $line)
{
    echo implode('<br>',$line), '<br>';
}
```

Both amount to the ssame thing